# Does less have an :any() or :matches() or :is() polyfill?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I am trying to do what is possible with the not-so-widely supported [:is()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/CSS/:is) selector in CSS, but in Less, so that it gets supported by all browsers. I couldn't find any information on such a function existing in Less, however.

An example of what I want to select is this:

```css
input:is([type="checkbox"], [type="radio"]) + label {
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="foo"> <label for="foo">Lorem</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" id="bar"> <label for="bar">Ipsum</label>
```

Now I know that Less has a way to do this without such a function, by simply nesting three selectors:

```
input {
    &[type="checkbox"], &[type="radio"] {
        & + label {
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    }
}
```

But to me that seems like a very convoluted way to do this.

So in short: is there a way using less to get the behaviour given in both of these examples, without dropping support for older browsers?